# React JS components are not fully rendered in mobile device

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react JS app deployed via heroku. On the desktop browser, I can see all the reactJS components that were rendered. But on the mobile, I can only see the components that were rendered within device size.

[This is when the components were initially loaded on mobile. There should be more cards when scrolled down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqt77.jpg)

[No more cards are visible because they were outside of view height when initially loaded. But they are there- I can scroll down to the bottom but just can't see the cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzxpU.png)

[however, if I turn off/on the device, or turn on other apps and come back to safari, I can magically see the cards within the device height.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp97h.png)

[again, there is nothing showned below the cards. If I iterate steps above, I can see the cards below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H680x.png)

Here's the link to the git repo. Div for the card is rendered within "src/components/messages.js"

https://github.com/jessicakwak/hitmeup-client

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles/Messages.css";
import "./styles/NewMessage.css";
import axios from "axios";
import Moment from "react-moment";

class Messages extends Component {
  // Data
  state = {
    messages: [],
    selected: this.props.selected,
    wallOpen: false
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(
      {
        selected: this.props.selected,
        wallOpen: this.props.wallOpen
      }, //async function, so do stuffs after this happened
      () => {
        let config = {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}` }
        };
        axios
          .get(
            `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/messages?channel=${this.state.selected}`,
            config
          )
          .then(res => {
            res.data.reverse();
            this.setState({ messages: res.data });
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
        this.forceUpdate();
      }
    );
  }

  
  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    //when the props inherited from Chat changed from [] to something
    this.setState(
      {
        selected: newProps.selected,
        wallOpen: newProps.wallOpen
      }, //async function, so do stuffs after this happened
      () => {
        let config = {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}` }
        };
        axios
          .get(
            `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/messages?channel=${this.state.selected}`,
            config
          )
          .then(res => {
            res.data.reverse();
            this.setState({ messages: res.data });
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
        this.forceUpdate();
      }
    );
  }

  // Render
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="messages">
        <div id="content">
          {this.state.messages.map(message => {
            return (
              <div className="message" key={message._id}>
                <div
                  className="userImageMessage"
                  style={{
                    backgroundImage: `url(${message.user.image})`
                  }}
                ></div>
                <div className="usrInfo">
                  <span className="user">{message.user.name}</span>
                  <span className="summaryText first">
                    {" "}
                    wants to meet up at{" "}
                  </span>
                  <span className="location">{message.location}</span>
                  <span className="summaryText"> on </span>
                  <span className="eventDate">
                    <Moment date={message.date} format="ll" />{" "}
                  </span>
                  <span> at </span>
                  <span className="eventTime">
                    <Moment date={message.date} format="LT" />
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div className="body">{message.text}</div>
                <span className="date">
                  <Moment
                    date={message.createDate}
                    format="MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"
                  />
                </span>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Messages;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please actually include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code (*not a link to your repo*) you think you have an issue with.

Comment: What version of react are you using? For all intents and purposes, [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) is deprecated. I also see several react anti-patterns, like the `setState` callback isn't really meant to run logic and set more state, and the fact alone that you call `forceUpdate` should have been a huge red flag something isn't right. Is the gist of this component: it mounts, fetches some data and sets some state, and if a prop updates, fetch data and sets some state again?

Comment: I added in forceupdate trying to fix this issue :,(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It still isn't clear what the issue actually is, but these updates should get your component code in better shape.

Issues:

- Saving props into state is an antipattern, just consume from props
- `setState` isn't intended to "chain" multiple synchronous state updates, use lifecycle functions instead
- Provide sufficient initial state and just fetch data in `componentDidMount`
- Data fetch really only dependent on `props.selected`, so no need to store that in state first
- `componentWillReceiveProps` is pretty much deprecated, use `componentDidUpdate`
- `forceUpdate` should really almost *never* be necessary

Solution:

- Factor out the data fetch into a function (versus `setState` callback`): DRY Principle
- Consume `props.selected` for data fetch: Single source of truth
- Fetch data in `componentDidMount`: use lifecycle function
- Utilize `componentDidUpdate` to compare previous and current `props.selected` values and refetch data: use lifecycle function

*Note: I don't see how `wallOpen` is used, so left that behavior in place*

```
// Data
state = {
  messages: [],
  wallOpen: this.props.wallOpen, // just set initial wallopen from props
};

fetchMessages = () => {
  const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}` }
  };
  axios
    .get(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/messages?channel=${this.props.selected}`,
      config
    )
    .then(res => {
      res.data.reverse();
      this.setState({ messages: res.data });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchMessages();
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const { selected, wallOpen } = this.props;

  // if selected prop changed, refetch data
  if (prevProps.selected !== selected) {
    this.fetchMessages();
  }

  // if new wallOpen prop changed, store it
  if (prevProps.wallOpen !== wallOpen) {
    this.setState({ wallOpen });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks so much for your answer! I figured out. It is definitely an issue with componentWillMount() deprecation issue. In the chat.js (Chat component that has messages & sidebar component) when I change componenetWillMount() to UNSAFE_componentWillMount() it loads all the messages correctly on the mobile. I just finished a dev boot camp, and this is the lifecycle they taught us so I was sticking to it... But from now on I should use updated cycle methods!! Thanks a BUNCH!

Comment: Also that wallOpen is not used I know :) I was experimenting with where to put that variable... (sidebar, chat or messages...) I'm refactoring my code a bit. I def should update all the lifecycles in all the components too.

Comment: @JessicaKwak Sorry that bootcamp is teaching with such dated material. React "deprecated" these legacy lifecycle functions in v[16.3.0](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1630-march-29-2018), way back in March 2018! React provides a [utility](https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod#rename-unsafe-lifecycles)  go through a project and rename (prepend the `UNSAFE_`) to the deprecated lifecycle functions.